# Flutter: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, mobile, voip

I try to handle message notifications in the background and do something when I receive the notification in the background. On android all thing are good but in ios
when I receive a notification the app return this error

> Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=561015905 "Session activation
> failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Session activation failed}
> flutter_callkit_incoming/SwiftFlutterCallkitIncomingPlugin.swift:215:
> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
> flutter_callkit_incoming/SwiftFlutterCallkitIncomingPlugin.swift:215:
> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
> * thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
> frame #0: 0x00000001b68aca2c libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_runtime_on_report libswiftCore.dylib`:
> ->  0x1b68aca2c <+0>: ret
> libswiftCore.dylib`: 0x1b68aca30 <+0>: b      0x1b68aca2c               ; _swift_runtime_on_report libswiftCore.dylib`:
> 0x1b68aca34 <+0>: adrp   x8, 366469
> 0x1b68aca38 <+4>: ldrb   w0, [x8, #0x994]
> Target 0: (Runner) stopped.

Then the app stopped directly.

What is the problem?

Note: I added these permissions:

```html
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
    <string>voip</string>
    <string>processing</string>
</array>
```

but I get the same error.

Comment: The problem is that plug-in doesn't have very good Swift code. It force unwraps an optional `uuid` that was created from the incoming notification.  It would be better to fallback to its own `uuid` if it fails to create one from the incoming notification.

Comment: but also i facing one issue when accept the call from background the app in ios not opened liked in android
and sometimes return this text in console
[BackgroundTask] Background Task 120 ("Flutter debug task"), was created over 30 seconds ago. In applications running in the background, this creates a risk of termination. Remember to call UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(_:) for your task in a timely manner to avoid this.
@Paulw11

Answer (score -2):

You only need two capabilities to achieve it.

1. Background fetch
2. Remote notifications

[image: View]

The above-written lines must be under the `<dict>` tag in the `Info.plist` file.

Comment: Please use code blocks, not images